# Finding common column value for set of another column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this dataframe. I have selected three random users from my data. I want to select common movies between these selected users in my dataframe.

```
df 

  userId             movieId  ratings   
0       1                 500      3.5
1       1                 600      4.5
2       1                 700      2.0
3       1                 800      4.0
4       2                 500      3.5
5       2                 600      4.5
6       2                 9400     2.0
7       3                 800      4.0
8       3                 600      2.0
9       3                 500      4.0
```

Expected Outcome:

```
  userId             movieId  ratings   
0       1                 500      3.5
1       2                 500      3.5
2       3                 500      4.0
3       1                 600      4.5
4       2                 600      4.5
5       3                 600      2.0
```

Actually, I have this approach to this problem. But I would appreciate it, someone takes a different approach.

```
def usersToMovies(rand_users):
    df1 = df.groupby('movieId')['userId'].apply(list).reset_index(name='users')
    # Check for rand_users in each list of users and filter rows.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), so for not common `movieId` columns are created missing values, so you can remove them by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and reshape back by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot(index='userId', columns='movieId', values='ratings')
         .dropna(axis=1)
         .unstack()
         .reset_index(name='ratings'))
print (df1)
   movieId  userId  ratings
0      500       1      3.5
1      500       2      3.5
2      500       3      4.0
3      600       1      4.5
4      600       2      4.5
5      600       3      2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a direct selection from the dataframe. The benefit of that approach is to keep the original index if it matters:

```
selection = df[df['movieId'].isin(df[['userId', 'movieId']].groupby('movieId').count()
                                  .reset_index().query('userId > 1')['movieId'])]
```

It gives:

```
   userId  movieId  ratings
0       1      500      3.5
1       1      600      4.5
3       1      800      4.0
4       2      500      3.5
5       2      600      4.5
7       3      800      4.0
8       3      600      2.0
9       3      500      4.0
```